# Python - Search through a list of known strings in multiple JSON files and create report of group matches with a percent match

Tags: python, json, search

I'm trying to find which JSON files in a single directory have the same data or similar then report which files are the closest match by percentage against each only match strings after a known string in each JSON file. Could anyone help with creating a Python script to output the results to a report file?

As a start I'm looking at this but I'd like it to iterate though the files with without having to specify the string and output a report with the similarities(%) see example;

```
import os

search_path = ("/home/...")
file_type = (".json")
search_str = ("'Apple-active':True", "'Apple-active':False")

if not (search_path.endswith("/") or search_path.endswith("\\") ): 
    search_path = search_path + "/"
                                     
if not os.path.exists(search_path):
    search_path ="."

for fname in os.listdir(path=search_path):

if fname.endswith(file_type):
    for ss in search_str:
        fo = open(search_path + fname)
        line = fo.readline()
        line_no = 1
        while line != '' :
            index = line.find(ss)
            if ( index != -1) :
                print(fname, "[", line_no, ",", index, "] ", line, sep="")
            line = fo.readline()  
            line_no += 1
    fo.close()'
```

Example of JSON files data;

> "'Apple-value':1",
> "'Apple-active':True",
> "'Banana-value':1",
> "'Banana-active':True"

Current output to terminal;

> store1.json   'Apple-active':True
>
> store4.json   'Apple-active':True
>
> shop25.json   'Apple-active':True
>
> cafe2.json    'Apple-active':True
>
> store5.json   'Apple-active':False
>
> shop6.json    'Apple-active':False,

**Ideal Report example;**

> **100% matched**
>
> Strings matched;
>
> "'Apple-value':5",
> "'Apple-active':True",
> "'Banana-value':10",
> "'Banana-active':False" ...
>
> Strings not matched; None
>
> Files with above Strings matched 100%;
>
> store1.json store4.json shop25.json cafe2.json
>
> **93% matched**
>
> Strings matched;
>
> "'Apple-value':3",
> "'Apple-active':False",
> "'Banana-active':False",
>
> Strings not matched;
>
> "'Banana-value':" Difference range 30 - 200
>
> ...
>
> Files with above Strings matched 93%;
>
> store5.json shop6.json

Thanks

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-use-glob-function-to-find-files-recursively-in-python/ might make finding the files easier